# PowerShell with batch file variables unable to work over network

Tags: powershell, batch-file, networking

I have a batch file that runs to prompt for variables and then pipelines them into a ps1 file to install a network printer.  The variables pipe into the .ps1 file fine and install a network printer on my computer fine.  But once I try to target a computer on the network it fails.  If I run the PowerShell script and have it prompt for the variables it works fine across network.  For some reason the function of using the batch file causes issues with the network functions.

Here is the batch file:

```batch
@echo off
set /p var1="What is your HP printer IP address?"
set /p var2="What do you want to name your printer?"
set /p var3="What is your computer serial number?"

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\600161236\Desktop\PrintVar3.ps1" %var1% %var2% %var3%
```

Here is the PowerShell file:

```bsh
Param(
    [string]$var1,
    [string]$var2,
    [string]$var3
)

Add-PrinterPort -Name $var1 -PrinterHostAddress $var1 -ComputerName $var3
Add-Printer -ComputerName $var3 -Name $var2 -DriverName "HP Universal Printing PS" -Port $var1
```

Error message is:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why dont' you acces the environment variables directly in the script $Env:var1 and pass them quoted. Your image shows a space in the name, how should that be properly passed without quoting?

Comment: I have no issues passing the variables when it comes to a local instance of the batch file and script running, but over the network it fails.

I'm using a batch file first as we are looking to integrate with another system that can't interface with PowerShell apparently.